# How can i install 'RDRPOSTagger'?

Tags: python, nlp, tags, part-of-speech

How can i use 'RDRPOSTagger' for french,

I need use 'RDRPOSTagger' for french, but i don't how i do to install or inclure this library

```
r = RDRPOSTagger() 
r.constructSCRDRtreeFromRDRfile("RDRPOSTagger-master/Models/POS/French.RDR") # Load POS tagging model for French 
DICT = readDictionary("../Models/POS/French.DICT") # Load a French lexicon 
r.tagRawSentence(DICT, "Cette annonce a fait l' effet d' une véritable bombe . ")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-c07a37f4fd93> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 r = RDRPOSTagger()
      6 r.constructSCRDRtreeFromRDRfile("RDRPOSTagger-master/Models/POS/French.RDR") # Load POS tagging model for French
      7 DICT = readDictionary("../Models/POS/French.DICT") # Load a French lexicon

NameError: name 'RDRPOSTagger' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `artagger`, a Python implementation. Here's the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/franziz/artagger/), and to get it via pip, it's a simple `pip install artagger`.

Comment: thank you but, it's not the same library !! i try it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("data.table")
install.packages("RDRPOSTagger", repos = "http://www.datatailor.be/rcube", type = "source")
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/bnosac/RDRPOSTagger and above at the right, click the green button- then download the zip file. Unzip it, then try the following:

```
devtools::install("file path to the master file locally")
```

or install the downloaded zip file on the R Studio GUI:
[image: Install package from GUI]

then click install.